# Mongo Unwind child object array to root as plain array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Suppose I have a simple collection like this:

```
[
  {
    Brands: [ 
                { BID: 1, Prods: [ { PID: 10 }, { PID: 11 } ] },
                { BID: 2, Prods: [ { PID: 20 }, { PID: 21 } ] }
           ]
  },
  {
    Brands: [
                { BID: 3, Prods: [ { PID: 30 }, { PID: 31 }, { PID: 32 } ] }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to extract all unique `PID` from `Prods`, so the result would be:

```
[10,11,20,21,30,31,32]
```

I could get close to this doing this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "AllProds": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$Brands.Prods",
          "as": "elem",
          "in": "$$elem.PID"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

But the result is not a simple array, its a array of objects with the `PID` inside of it:

```
[
  {
    "AllProds": [
      [ 10, 11 ],
      [ 20, 21 ]
    ],
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000")
  },
  {
    "AllProds": [
      [ 30, 31, 32 ]
    ],
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000001")
  }
]
```

[Here is is the playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LTMn97hsHrz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't exactly require `$map` here. Just unwind the outer array, then
the inner array and group them together

```
db.getCollection('SampleCollection').aggregate([
    {
        $unwind:"$Brands"
    },
    {
        $unwind:"$Brands.Prods"
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            _id:null,
            PIDs: {$push:"$Brands.Prods.PID"}//use $addToSet instead of $push if you do not wish to allow duplicates
        }
    }    
])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do 2 more $unwind to flatten the arrays. Then use $group and $addToSet to get the result.

Here is the [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/GHiaetNcOXV) for your reference.

Answer (score 1):

- `$group` by null and make `Brands` array
- `$project`, `$reduce` to iterate loop of `$Brands` array, `$reduce` to iterate loop of inner array of brands and concat arrays using `$concatArrays`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      Brands: { $push: "$Brands.Prods.PID" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      Brands: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$Brands",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              {
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$$this",
                  initialValue: [],
                  in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5FVqkPm9IfU)